# Flutter: Not all model data is available at initialization

Tags: flutter, dart

Lets assume I have a model represented below:

```dart
class Car {

    Car({this.id, this.name});

    int id;
    final String name;

}
```

In this class I do not know the id initially. The way I would get the `id` is by having an API call to get it.

What would be the best approach to initializing and using the `Car` model until the `id` is eventually populated?

I have an approach where I give an id number initially (locally generated) until I am able to replace it with the right one.

Comment: The Question is too broad, the answer really depends on what you're trying to achieve. In most of the cases the id can stay null until it's received ( can be used to send the object in a POST request or to save in a local database ), but it isn't always the right option.

Comment: I agree that its generic to some extent. The reason for my question is that I have no control over the id generation (It happens server side). I would like to be able use this object locally without having to wait for the `id` to be generated.

Answer (score 0):

I will make id nullable and use `copyWith` method to reassign, while I like to have `final`

```dart
class Car {
  const Car({this.id, required this.name});

  final int? id;
  final String name;

  Car copyWith({
    int? id,
    String? name,
  }) {
    return Car(
      id: id ?? this.id,
      name: name ?? this.name,
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: The app in its current form is not null safe. But I want to approach your solution by placing null initially and still using `copyWith`. Would you suggest not having an initial `id` set? The model's current responsibility does not include fetching the required data as its the responsibility of the respective service.

Comment: I will prefer using null, because we don't know the id. I only set initial value if it acts default value